# Server 500 on Azure Rest Api call while attempting to put xml data

Tags: powershell, azure-rest-api, azure-rm

i'm migrating AzureRm pwsh scripts to the azure cli. i've given up on using the cli for this case. i'm just trying to emulate the web call that the AzureRm function calls (i used the `-WhatIf` flag to render the uri)

Here's the pwsh AzureRm that works:

```
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                    -ResourceName ($AppName + "/AntMDS/" + $SettingName) `
                    -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/firstPartyApps/settings" `
                    -Properties $SettingProperties `
                    -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 `
                    -Force `
                    | Out-Null
```

i'm trying to submit values, some of which are xml strings. here's the code that I use:

```
function Set-GenevaAntMdsSetting($ResourceGroupName, $AppName, $SettingName, $SettingValue)
{
    $SettingProperties = @{}
    $SettingProperties.FirstPartyId = "AntMDS"
    $SettingProperties.SettingName = $SettingName
    # The following value DOES NOT get converted to base 64 for the AzureRM call
    # $SettingProperties.SettingValue = $SettingValue
    $SettingProperties.SettingValue = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($SettingValue))
    
    # New-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    #                     -ResourceName ($AppName + "/AntMDS/" + $SettingName) `
    #                     -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/firstPartyApps/settings" `
    #                     -Properties $SettingProperties `
    #                     -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 `
    #                     -Force `
    #                     | Out-Null
    
    $body = $SettingProperties | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    Write-Verbose "getting active subscription id"
    $subscriptionid = (az account show --query id -o tsv)
    Write-Verbose "subscription id retrieved: $subscriptionid"
    $uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionid/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/" + `
           "providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/$AppName/firstPartyApps/AntMDS/settings/$($SettingName)?api-version=2022-03-01"
    Write-Verbose "Getting auth token for rest call"
    $token = (az account get-access-token  -s $subscriptionid --query accessToken -o tsv)
    Write-Verbose "Auth token recieved"
    $headers = @{"Content-Type"="application/json";
                 "Authorization"="Bearer $token"}
    Write-Verbose "Attempting to post data to azure rest api: $uri"
    Write-Verbose "headers: $headers"
    Write-Verbose "body: $body"
    try{
        $client = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new()
        $msg = [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage]::new()
        $msg.Headers.Add('Accept','application/json')
        $msg.Headers.Add('Authorization','Bearer ' + $token)
        $msg.Content = [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new($body, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8, 'application/json')
        
        $msg.Method = 'PUT'
        $msg.RequestUri = $uri
        $response = $client.SendAsync($msg). `
                            GetAwaiter(). `
                            GetResult()
        #$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method PUT -Headers $headers -Body $body
        Write-Verbose $response
    }catch{
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        throw
    }
}
```

i keep getting a server 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

after running some postman gets on the url i got from rummaging around in the AzureRM func (running with the `-WhatIf` flag) I realized there was an id value that I assume the AzureRM function constructed. here's the azure cli implementation:

```
function Set-GenevaAntMdsSetting([string]$ResourceGroupName, [string]$AppName, [string]$SettingName, [string]$SettingValue)
{
    # Remove xml formatting space like tag indentation and line feeds between tags and in attributes
    $SettingValue = $SettingValue -replace "(\s?\n+\s+|\n)", ""

    $SettingProperties = @{}
    $SettingProperties.FirstPartyId = "AntMDS"
    $SettingProperties.SettingName = $SettingName
    $SettingProperties.SettingValue = $SettingValue
    
    $tempfile = New-TemporaryFile
    $SettingProperties | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Out-File $tempfile.FullName
    $SubscriptionId = (az account show --query id -o tsv)
    $result = `
    az resource create --properties "@$($tempfile.FullName)" `
                       --id "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/$AppName/firstPartyApps/AntMDS/settings/$SettingName" `
                       --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/firstPartyApps/settings" `
                       --name $SettingName `
                       --api-version "2015-08-01" `
                       | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Verbose $result
    Remove-Item $tempfile
}
```